# Last.fm-like recommendations for books?

Tags: webapp-rec

I like the way that [Last.fm](http://www.last.fm/) takes what music I listen to and recommends music of a similar genre that I haven't listened to before (or not very often).

I have discovered some good music this way. I would like to enter the books I am reading at the moment and find other books based on the books I read.

I don't want to make "friends" with people to find books that way like some sites seem to do. ([Goodreads.com](http://www.goodreads.com/) etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Amazon for this. It recommends you books based on your viewing and buying history. I know it's not built for that, but on numerous occasions I've been surprised on how good a job it does.

Comment: Does it let you tell you what books you already own, or does it only know what books you bought from Amazon?

Comment: It knows books you bought on Amazon, plus books you viewed on Amazon (without actually buying them). Not ones you own, no.

Comment: Actually yes, you can. It's a little tricky to find, but there's an "I own it" button under the "Rate This Item to Improve Your Recommendations" section. Click this on any book or product page, and it will be added the [Improve Your Recommendations](https://www.amazon.com/gp/yourstore/iyr) account page. I keep a small library of good books I own to keep the recommendations on topic. I think this is the best answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [LibraryThing](http://www.librarything.com/) to be very good, but you really need to pay up since the free version limits how big your library can be.

Comment: I agree. Once you've entered your books it automatically tells you who has books you've already got and gives automatic recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new site called [GetGlue.com](http://getglue.com), which aims to do Netflix-like recommendations of all sorts of media, including Books. So far, the Books section is one of their bigger sections, along with Music and Movies. But they also allow you to rate games and other media/interests.

I'm not from GetGlue, and I kind of hate their Google Chrome extension, which puts a toolbar across certain pages outside of GetGlue.com. But that's an add-on, and the site itself is a decent concept. It might be worth a look for your goals.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.whatshouldireadnext.com/ maybe what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm that seems the sort of idea but it does have the feel of a geocities web app.

Comment: 90's UI FTW. What do you expect? it's probably created by people who spend more time reading books than writing code. :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted elsewhere, Amazon does a good job.  If it is recommending things based too tightly on recent purchases, then log out, browse to your favorite books of the moment then look at recommendations.  You'll still get surprisingly good recommendations without distracting amazon by the fact that two years ago you bought a bunch of cookbooks or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

[Shelfari](http://www.shelfari.com/). It's more of a social cataloging site though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [YourNextRead](http://www.yournextread.com/us/) or [WhichBook.net](http://www.whichbook.net/default.aspx). Former has GoodReads integration too.

Answer (score 0):

[Dozen Books](http://dozen.softover.com) does almost exactly what you want - it does recommendations only, based on ratings of books you've read